# ASP net Core Razor Pages - split models for EF and views

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I would really like to get some additional input from some other devs.
Currently, I'm working on a small project that uses just some database tables. What I was thinking about is, if it makes sense to split the models to database and view models. Currently, only DB models are in use, which is also used in all the pages/views.

Originally I thought it might be a good idea to have a clean separation of them in case some DB changes come up. 
But honestly, I don't see an advantage of splitting it up. If columns should get renamed it's possible to use some attributes without having an impact on the UI.

The only reason for to split it would be to not load all the columns if not needed. Right now when view fetches some information from the DB, all columns get loaded. But that is very less traffic, even if it's not needed.
I can remember that also MS was mentioned to split it up in some previous documentation about ASP.Net Core. But seems they changed. Also, the documents about EF are not mentioning any separation of models.

Comment: There are people who do this from the outset and then there are others who later wish they'd done it from the outset.

Comment: Does that mean you would always split it? Better at the beginning instead of later? But why exactly?

Comment: A small projects is better place to setup everything more OO way and to learn at the same time. Yes it seems an overhead at the time, but you aren't just building an CRUD application. There will always be business need changes in the view which will cause you to add properties on entities (but not in database), which will keep increasing size of a single entity. There will be validations or the lists which will be needed in the project where you will not like to have whole entities being passed. MS  examples are focused on making easy EF access and not focused on design as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to split the solution into Clean Architecture (Web, Infrastructure and Core Layer). 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/common-web-application-architectures

Find it the best fitting one and would be very easy to extend when application starts growing.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar thoughts (esp when I've used string backing fields for JSON blobs). You could use anonymous types to limit the returned data.

Like this example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval)

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .OrderByDescending(blog => blog.Rating)
    .Select(blog => new
    {
        Id = blog.BlogId,
        Url = StandardizeUrl(blog.Url)
    })
    .ToList();
```

EF Core 2.1 also introduced [Query Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) which can help make the relationship between your view objects and the db model more clear.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But this would only be possible if no additional properties are needed for blogs in the view. Which is currently fine but not sure if it will be like that also in the future.